# I am using Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE for location . Does it require WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or any other storage permission?

Tags: android

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 
 1);
```

I am using above code and letting my users to choose download location. File that user downloads gets stored in that download location. I am also using
DocumentFile.delete();
to delete that file.

In my use cases does WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is required? Does it requires any other storage permisson other than WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE? Because as I can see Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE can be launched without any permission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` requires no runtime permissions - that's kind of the entire point. Since the user is explicitly involved with selecting the folder, the user is completely aware with what directory your app has read/write access to.

Comment: Hey, just one more question, what about Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT? Is there any runtime permission required?

Comment: No. The same thing. But maybe you dont get always a write permission.

Comment: Thanks for help @blackapps. I am using another code snippet in my app to upload file; In that snippet I am using Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT for getting file and uploading it. I am not writing anything just getting file and uploading, so in that case it will work fine without any permission am I right?

Comment: If you use the obtained uri directly, yes. Not if you use silly functions like getrealpathfromuri and such.